# Cannot invoke method add() on null object while adding to Java List

Tags: java, list

I am getting a nullpointer exception while trying to add a string to list inside for loop:

```
List<WebElement> ordercharges = browser.driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='order-charges-amount ng-binding']"))
            println("Order charges found are"+ordercharges.size())
            for(int i=0;i<ordercharges.size();i++)
            {
                String charges =  ordercharges.get(i).getText()
                liteshippingcharges.add(charges)
            }
```

Here is the error details: Cannot invoke method add() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method add() on null object

Comment: That means your `List` is `null`, it is not the one you have initialized in your example code. `liteshippingcharges` is `null`, now you have to find out why.

Comment: Basically this means that `liteshippingcharges` is null.

Comment: As a side note, I'd strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions, leading to names such as `orderCharges` and `liteShippingCharges`.

Comment: Thanks @deHaar you are correct i forgot to initialize list.